# Problem with ORDER BY and DISTINCT ON in rails 6 App

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I want to run this query:

```
@tables = policy_scope(Table).active
                             .where(private: false)
                             .left_outer_joins(:occupants)
                             .or(current_user.active_tables
                             .left_outer_joins(:occupants))
                             .or(policy_scope(Table)
                             .active
                             .where(private: true)
                             .left_outer_joins(:occupants)
                             .where(occupants: current_user.current_seated_occupant))
                             .or(policy_scope(Table)
                             .active
                             .where(private: true)
                             .left_outer_joins(:occupants)
                             .where(occupants: current_user.occupants.invited))
                             .distinct
                             .order('occupants.status')
```

But I get this error:

> PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list LINE 1: ...id" = $7 AND "occupants"."status" = $8)) ORDER BY occupants.... ^

Generated SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT "tables".* FROM "tables" LEFT OUTER JOIN "occupants" ON "occupants"."table_id" = "tables"."id" WHERE "tables"."active" = $1 AND ((("tables"."private" = $2 OR "tables"."user_id" = $3) OR "tables"."private" = $4 AND "tables"."id" = $5) OR "tables"."private" = $6 AND "tables"."id" IN (SELECT "occupants"."table_id" FROM "occupants" WHERE "occupants"."user_id" = $7 AND "occupants"."status" = $8)) ORDER BY occupants.status) subquery_for_count  [["active", true], ["private", false], ["user_id", 20], ["private", true], ["id", nil], ["private", true], ["user_id", 20], ["status", 2]]
```

Here is my Model relation:

```
class Table < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :occupants, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```
class Occupant < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :table
end
```

I tried lots of solutions from Stackoverflow to other similar questions. but i could not solve my error.

My rails version is `6.0.2`

I will be really grateful if someone could point out what is going wrong in this case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the generated SQL query ?

Comment: LeGEC i've edited my question puted generated SQL query.

Comment: I think you can debug your code and the query it generates : for example, why would you want to add `ORDER BY` on a subquery, if you only want to `SELECT count(*)` from it ?

Comment: Actually i want to order by data with relational Model's (Occupant) `status` field. for that i added order in my query. and also i want uniq record.

Comment: You can add a select statement to the query chain, `select('tables.*', occupants.status)`. Im just suggesting this because of the error saying that these need to be in the select. list. If that didn't work, I'd try to use raw sql to make the query using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`. For complex queries like this, I tend to reach for sql. Arel would work too, but I thought I read the maintainers made that api private again, not 100% sure on that tho